# Convert Date and Time in required format "Jun 9 18:04:42:"

Tags: python, datetime

Current Format is Jun 9 18:04:42:

Required Format is 09/06/2021 18:04:42:00

There is no year in current format, but I need to add it.
I have tried following code

s= 'Jun 9 18:04:42:'

'''

```
  def convert_to_date(s):
    if s!='None':

        if s=='':
            return s
        else:
            print ("to unpack values:",s)
            s=s.replace(' ', ':')

            f_month,f_day,f_hour,f_minute,f_seconds,f_miliseconds = s.split(':')

            s = str(f_month) +'-' + str(f_day) + ' ' + str(f_hour) + ':' + str(f_minute)+':'+str(f_seconds) +':'+str(f_miliseconds)

            print ("unpacked values:",s)

            return s
```

'''
output is: 'Jun-9 18:04:42:'

Comment: Year is always 2021 then?

Comment: Do you want to get the current `date and time` 
Or
Just convert the `date and time`

Comment: Just convert date and time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **`dateutil`** module's [`parser.parse`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html#dateutil.parser.parse) method, which can parse a range of differently formatted date strings and return a `datetime.datetime` object. Then you can convert it to any other format using [`strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime) function:

```
>>> from dateutil.parser import parse
>>> dt = parse('Jun 9 18:04:42').strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S:00')
>>> print (dt)
09/06/2021 18:04:42:00
```